# Error compiling shader '[object WebGLShader]':ERROR: 0:82: 'sqrt' : no matching overloaded function found

Tags: glsl, webgl, glsles

I am doing a calculation in GLSL (Shading Language) which is as follows

```
int N = 3;
  float sigma_H = 5
 for(int i = 0 ;i < 3 ; i++){
float sigma_H_i = sigma_H * sqrt(3) * pow(2,(N - (i + 1))) / sqrt(pow(4,N) - 1.0);
}
```

The Error I am getting is

```
webgl-utils.js:66 *** Error compiling shader '[object WebGLShader]':ERROR: 0:82: 'sqrt' : no matching overloaded function found 
ERROR: 0:82: 'pow' : no matching overloaded function found 
ERROR: 0:82: 'pow' : no matching overloaded function found 

WARNING: 0:82: 'sqrt' : operation result is undefined for the values passed in 
ERROR: 0:104: '' : syntax error
```

I knew the error is in the following block of code because as soon as I remove following line it compile correctly

```
 float sigma_H_i = sigma_H * sqrt(3) * pow(2,(N - (i + 1))) / sqrt(pow(4,N) - 1.0);
```

Can Any one please tell me why am I getting this error that there is no pow function although I knew that there is 'pow()' function in GLSL from[OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) Quick Reference Guide](http://mew.cx/glsl_quickref.pdf)

[image]

I am using Google Chrome Browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your code is invalid. According to the GLSL ES spec:

> When the built-in functions are specified below, where the input arguments (and corresponding output)
>   can be `float`, `vec2`, `vec3`, or `vec4`, *genType* is used as the argument.

You are calling it with an `int`, and GLSL does not do any implicit conversions (in contrast to C), so the correct syntax would have to be something like

```
float sigma_H_i = sigma_H * sqrt(3.0) * pow(2.0,(float(N - (i + 1)))) / sqrt(pow(4.0,float(N)) - 1.0);
```